# Set is equal to its closure in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I'm trying to determine some criteria for when the closure of a closed irreducible set $X$ of $\mathbb A^n$ is equal to the set itself. That is if $\overline{X}$ is the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb P^n$ and $X$ is a closed irreducible set of $\mathbb A^n$ then (by identifying $\mathbb A^n$ with $\mathbb P^n_{x_0,\dots,x_n} \setminus V_{\mathbb P^n}(x_n)$) when exactly is $X = \overline{X}$?

My thinking is this is perhaps true only when $X$ is the set of a single equivalence class of $\mathbb P^n$ with one nonzero entry, is this the case? Namely, is $X = \overline{X}$ if and only if $X = \{[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1} : 1]\}$?

We are working over a field $K$ that is algebraically closed on characteristic zero.

Comment: You mean a single point?

Comment: Is your field algebraically closed?

Comment: @TedShifrin my understanding is that the projective space is comprised of congruence classes of points where elements are congruent if and only if they are scalar multiples of each other. although i suppose it would literally just be one point in this case yes

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes, i have added that as a condition now